# React: how to maintain performance when updating a large parent record from a controlled child input field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Imagine a React page that allows users to edit a bill (invoice). The bill has a fair number of editable fields, say 100. Additionally, a bill can have any number of line items. Let's imagine 100 of them, each with, say, 20 fields.

If the bill is the "parent," and is rendered by a React component, the line items are "children," each rendered by a "child" component.

I'm maintaining the state of the bill (and its line items) in the parent component, which feels right.

I want to use controlled input fields in the child (line item) component. However, this means, at least naively, that every keypress results in a state update in the parent (bill) component, and some re-renders, even if I use React.memo judiciously.

Performance has quickly gotten unacceptably slow, even with as few as 10 line items, like a 500-800ms lag on each keypress. I've done a fair bit of performance sleuthing, and have a couple of potential answers, but I'm not going to report them here, in order not to thwart any routes to the best answer.

There must be a common solution to this, no? I'd like to do it without one of the form libraries, though I'm not totally opposed to that.

The stripped-down example below, just to demonstrate the basic architecture. **The example doesn't have a performance issue.** :-)

Help! What's the magic that I'm missing to keep this performant?

````
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  invoiceNumber: "ABC123",
  customer: "Phil's Dills",
  lineItems: [
    { index: 0, item: "Pickles", quantity: 2 },
    { index: 1, item: "Pickle Juice", quantity: 5 },
  ]
}

export function Bill() {
  const [ bill, setBill ] = useState(INITIAL_STATE);

  function updateBill(updatedLineItem) {
    const newLineItems = [...bill.lineItems];
    newLineItems[updatedLineItem.index] = updatedLineItem;
    setBill({
      ...bill,
      lineItems: newLineItems
    })
  }

  return(
    <div id="parent">
    <h1>Bill {bill.invoiceNumber} for {bill.customer}</h1>
    {bill.lineItems.map((lineItem) => (
      <LineItem key={lineItem.index} line={lineItem} updateBill={updateBill} />
    ))}
    </div>
    );
}

function LineItem({ line, updateBill }) {
  function updateField(e) {
    updateBill({
      ...line,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    }); 
  }

  return(
    <div id="child">
      <input id="quantity" value={line.quantity} onChange={updateField} />
      <input id="item" value={line.item} onChange={updateField} />
    </div>
    );
}```
````

Comment: As Nick said you should wrap functions in `useCallback` so they aren't re-created during re-rendered. But as for your problem, if I wrap your `LineItem` component in React.memo then I can render thousands of inputs with zero typing delay, since as I type only that specific input re-renders.

Comment: FYI - With the React Dev Tools you can visualise the re-renders and test your different approaches. Also, if I'm correct, LineItem will rerender because an object is given as props (line), if you use primitives as props, React can distinguish what has changed.

Comment: Thank you, @Jayce444. As I mentioned, my example does not have a performance problem. In the actual case, there is much more going on, which makes re-renders considerably more expensive. And as also mentioned, I've also gone down the React.memo route.

Comment: Thanks, @wiesson. I have indeed been using React Dev Tools in Chrome. Interestingly, even though a console.log in my child component indicates that I'm not re-rendering, Dev Tools Performance shows that time is allocated to all the children. That's been the puzzling piece of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue actually is that you're recreating `updateBill` every time this component re-renders, meaning every single child component will also re-render because they all receive `updateBill` as a prop. Consider using `useCallback` to memoize the `updateBill` function:

```
const updateBill = useCallback(updatedLineItem => {
  setBill(bill => {
    const newLineItems = [...bill.lineItems];
    newLineItems[updatedLineItem.index] = updatedLineItem;
    return {
      ...bill,
      lineItems: newLineItems
    }
  })
}, []);
```

Comment: I have tried remedying this by using a custom "props-comparing" function with React.memo on the child components (leaving updateBill out of the equation). Didn't seem to make a difference. But I haven't actually tried useCallback on updateBill. I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: OK, now I remember the issue with wrapping `updateBill` in `useCallback`: `updateBill` has the `bill` object as a dependency. Since `bill` is getting updated on every keystroke (by definition), it's going to trigger a recreation of `updateBill`, I think. Not sure how I can make `updateBill` not have a dependency, one way or another, on `bill`...?

Comment: Update: `useCallback` made little difference. I even made `updateBill` a pure function (with the child record passing the `record` value back to the parent...to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for your thoughts and suggestions. You helped clear my head, and I found the problem. `bill`, which gets updated on every keypress, was a dependency to a `useEffect` hook that, as it turns out, was very expensive and caused a lot of re-renders. I refactored that `useEffect` and my keypress performance is now very acceptable, even in development mode.

Comment: This is a good reason why you should include all of the relevant code rather than just excerpts.

Consider looking into `React.useMemo()` which may also help in this scenario in the future. 

In general, creating arrow functions and pretty negligible CPU impact, so I would never worry about that

Comment: Fair enough, @DanPantry, although I think I would have scared off everyone with all the code! As I mentioned in my question, I had already used `React.useMemo`.